# Calculus of conditional expectation wrt $\sigma(B_1-B_s)$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, filtrations

On a classic probability space with $B$ a brownian motion.
How to prove for :
$$0\leq s<t\leq 1,\ \ \ \mathbb E (B_t-B_s\mid B_1-B_s)=\frac{t-s}{1-s}(B_1-B_s)$$

---

**What I have done:**
I am sure that we have the brownian filtration : $\mathcal F_s$ independant to $\sigma (B_1-B_s)$ and also $\mathcal F_t\vee \sigma (B_1) = \mathcal F_t\vee \sigma (B_1-B_s)$.
So then we can write :
$$\mathbb E (B_t-B_s\mid B_1-B_s)=\mathbb E (B_t-B_s\mid \mathcal F_s\vee \sigma (B_1))$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $X=B_t-B_s$ and $Y=B_1-B_s$. Now since $(X,Y)$ are jointly normaly distributed, with mean $0$ and variance $\Sigma$ you have $$E(X|Y=y)=E(X)+\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{Var(Y)}(y-E(Y))$$ which shall translate into your desired results.

Note $Cov(X,Y)=Cos(B_t-B_s,B_1-B_s)=t-s$ since $t\leq1$, and $Var(Y)=1-s$.

For joint normality you may look back at the properties of the Brownian Motion. For that see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Characterisations_of_the_Wiener_process). For conditional expectations see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case).

Comment: Do you have a proof of that (even an internet link) ? And how do you assert that $(X,Y)$ are jointly normaly distributed (they are not independant) ?

Comment: A proof for joint normality or the conditional expectation?

Comment: Yes both please

Comment: For $f$ a borelian function we can write : $B_1-B_s=f(B_1-B_t, B_t-B_s)$. Is it independant to $B_t-B_s$ ? I don't think so.

Comment: $B_1-B_s$ is not independent from $B_t-B_s$ for $s,t$ defined in the problem statement. See the edited post for links.

Comment: No but i am little bit confused : to be jointly normaly distributed x and y dont have to be independant ?

Comment: No theydo not need to be independent. Please refer to the exposition, as an example, to the link I gave to multivariate normal.

Comment: But I am always confused ... read this : [Two normally distributed random variables need not be jointly bivariate normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Two_normally_distributed_random_variables_need_not_be_jointly_bivariate_normal)

Comment: ... and I remind $t$ is like that $0\leq s<t\leq 1$

Comment: Note that this is a property of a Brownian motion to have increments jointly normally distributed.